# include nested views if exists in blade, laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to include another view if it exists. I have a main `page.blade.php` which should render the content of the selected page. in the back-end of the application I get a flat array with all the content in it (id and name). So now if a template exists I want to render it but first I need to check if the template actually exists.

I got the following code right now:

```
@foreach($flattenPage as $page)
    @if(file_exists('templates.'.strtolower($page['name'])))
        @include('templates.'.strtolower($page["name"]))
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The problem is that it won't get through the if statement. 
I also tried:

```
@if(file_exists('../templates/'.strtolower($page['name']).'.blade.php'))
```

The current template is `views/page/show.blade.php` and I need to render `views/templates/myContent.blade.php`

Comment: It's probably a relative path issue. Try `file_exists(base_path('resources/views/templates/'.strtolower($page['name']).'.blade.php'))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to determine if a view exists - you can use `exists` method ([as described in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views))

```
@if (view()->exists('templates.'.strtolower($page["name"])))
    @include('templates.'.strtolower($page["name"]))
@endif
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I'm dumb. Could you please demonstrate how multiple views would be passed into the above function?

Comment: @Tomk07 - you could just do multiple `@include`, one for each view you wanted to include there.

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel 5.2 you can also do this:

```
@includeIf('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Your code will look like this:

```
@foreach($flattenPage as $page)
    @includeIf('templates.'.strtolower($page["name"]))
@endforeach
```